# How to create a Pydantic model of a generic list with count?

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to create a model to verify this kind of structure:

```
{
   "count": <int>
   "items": [...]
}
```

where items itself can be any kind of model.

I tried

```
T = TypeVar("T")

class CountList(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    items: List[T]
    count: int
```

But when parsed with a other model items inside, I get a dict back and not an object.

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you asking, but check [Generic Models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#generic-models) to have a guide about how to implement them because it mentions the usage of the `GenericModel` class and you are not using it.